# How to suppress chapter numbers in page headings for select chapters?

Tags: header-footer, numbering, chapters

My book uses ordinary numbering for chapters and sections and is supposed to usually also show chapter numbers in the page headers (see the ordinary chapter example in my mwe). However, for select chapters and sections in my book such as the references I would like to suppress the chapter numbers in the page headers (as I also suppress the chapters numbers in the TOC). How can this be achieved?

MWE with explanations:

```
\documentclass[graybox,envcountchap,sectrefs]{svmono}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}        
\graphicspath{{Figures/}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1-3]
This is what normal chapters, sections as well as the respective numbering 
in headers and toc are supposed to look like.

%%% The problems start here
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References without numbering}
\chapter*{References without numbering}
\chaptermark{References without numbering}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Literaturetype X}
\section*{Literaturetype X}
\sectionmark{Literaturetype X}
\lipsum[1-3]
Because neither the references chapter nor the references sections, which are
used to distuingish different types of literature, are supposed to be numbered
 in the toc or page header, therefore chapter* is used. Since in this case the
 page header of chapter 1 would still be shown, chaptermark and sectionmark
 are used to adapt the page headers content to the references chapter and 
section. However, the chapter numbering in the page headers does still show 
although it is not supposed to. How can I modify chaptermark and section mark 
to not show the respective numberings in the page header?

\end{document}
```

My MWE with the used class (svmono.cls) implementation can be looked at and modfied here: https://www.overleaf.com/6700293jqghhf . Press "Project" to get access to the svmono.cls file, too.

Comment: But now there is a code…

Comment: @David Carlisle: I fully agree with you.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I couldn't figure out on how to include the mwe in the comments. I deleted the other one.

Comment: @kuuhkuuh you can't add code to comments but you could have edited the old question (although thanks for deleting, that also works)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `svmono` class has  commands for that: `\extrachapter` adds marks for the header, without a number, and `\Extrachapter` adds it to the `.toc`. 
\Extrachapter change line breaks into  word spaces for the table of contents, but it adds a huge space to the header, and it does not accept an optional argument. However  you can specify this optional argument with `\chaptermark` or `\sectionmark` commands.

Unfortunately, subsection are still numbered with the last numbered chapter. So I added `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}` before \Extrachapter:

```
\documentclass[graybox,envcountchap,sectrefs]{svmono}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{Figures/}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1-3]
This is what normal chapters, sections as well as the respective numbering
in headers and toc are supposed to look like.

%%% The problems start here
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\Extrachap{This is a long title therefore\\has a linebreak}%
\chaptermark{This is a long title therefore has a linebreak}
\section{Literaturetype X}

\lipsum[1-10]
Because neither the references chapter nor the references sections, which are
used to distuingish different types of literature, are supposed to be numbered
 in the toc or page header, therefore chapter* is used. Since in this case the
 page header of chapter 1 would still be shown, chaptermark and sectionmark
 are used to adapt the page headers content to the references chapter and
section. However, the chapter numbering in the page headers does still show
although it is not supposed to. How can I modify chaptermark and section mark
to not show the respective numberings in the page header?

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes, that works! Thanks a lot! However, still can't seem to get linebreaks now with \Extrachap[This is a long title therefore has \\ a linebreak]{This is a long title therefore has a linebreak} as described here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/335346/addcontentslinetoc-with-a-linebreak-or-newline-for-the-toc

Would you have an idea on how to handle that, now that I don't need  \addcontentsline but could use \Extrachap ?

Comment: @kuuhkuuh: `\Extrachapter` does not accept an optional argument (which you misused  anyway). Use `\chaptermark` instead. Please see my updated answer.