# \addcontentsline{toc} with a linebreak or newline for the TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, line-breaking, sv-classes

I use a `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{chaptername...}` with a long chapter name. As for some reason this chapter name shows up with the second line indented in my `toc`, I would like to find a way to manual set a `\newline` or `\\` to force a line break. While this does work with `\chapter[chapter\newline name]{chaptername}` it does not seem to work with `\addcontentsline`.

What can do the trick? I also looked into my `svmono` class to generally rule out indentations in second lines in the `toc`, but can't seem to find to change the settings:

```
\documentclass[graybox,envcountchap,sectrefs]{svmono}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}        
\graphicspath{{Figures/}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Pretty long chapter title that shouldn't 
be indented in the \\ second line}
\chapter*{This would be the chapter}
with its content

\end{document}
```

My MWE with the used class (`svmono.cls`) implementation can be looked at and modified [here](https://www.overleaf.com/6700839mstksz). Press "Project" to get access to the `svmono.cls` file too.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for the indentation is the missing chapter number which is usually added something like

`\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}chapter title}`

Leaving the argument of `\numberline{}` empty will produce the correct indentation, but will add also the dotted line.

`\usepackage{tocloft}` disables this by default.If the dotted line should appear, omit `\usepackage{tocloft}`.

Just in case of having more of this long wrapping titles: I've provided a command `\addchapterline{foo}` which writes the `foo` content to the `ToC`.

```
\documentclass[graybox,envcountchap,sectrefs]{svmono}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tocloft}
%\usepackage{graphicx}     % Not needed here    
%\graphicspath{{Figures/}} % Not needed here


\newcommand{\addchapterline}[1]{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents


\addchapterline{Pretty long chapter title that shouldn't 
be indented in the second line}

\chapter*{This would be the chapter}
with its content

\chapter{Numbered chapter}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I vote you!!!! :-)

Comment: The leader dots are the default for `svmono`.

Comment: @egreg: Well, as long as nobody complains or the O.P. does not really submit to Springer...